# Convert a list to CSV with customized logic for each row?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code to get the list.

```
$str = '[
    {"attrs": { "id": "A", "repeat": 2}},
    {"attrs": { "id": "B", "repeat": 3}}
    ]'
$json = $str | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I want to convert it to the CSV. The row should be repeated by the value of the `repeat` property.

```
id,repeat
A,2
A,2
B,3
B,3
B,3
```

The following code

```
$json | % { $_.attrs | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes AsNeeded | select -Skip 1 }
```

generates the following result. How to implement the log to repeat the rows? (The actual logic is more complex and the language feature such as `generator` can be helpful, however, Powershell seems to not have it.)

```
A,2
B,3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [range operator `..`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#range-operator-) and an inner loop:

```
$json.attrs | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($i in 1..$_.repeat) { $_ }
} | Export-Csv path\to\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to have the file with no headers, then [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.3) can also be outside the loop:

```
$json.attrs | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($i in 1..$_.repeat) { $_ }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -UseQuotes AsNeeded | Select-Object -Skip 1
```